# Azure Face Api Pricing?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

Hello I m strugling to understand the pricing of Azure Face Detect

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/

Face Detect is priced $1 per 1000 transaction but it doesn't say if each attributes is counted as a transaction?

so what will be the cost of face detect call that is like that:

returnFaceId = true

returnFaceLandmarks = true

returnFaceAttributes =  age, gender, smile, facialHair, glasses, emotion, hair, makeup, occlusion, accessories, blur, exposure , noise

is it counted as 1 transaction? or 1 + 1 + 13 = 15 transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states under the FAQ:

> **What constitutes a transaction for Face API?**
>
> [..snip..]
>
> For all other operations, each API call will be counted as a transaction.

This means that, if you're able to make one call returning all these attributes, it counts as one transaction.

Comment: that would be awesome, but it's disturbing as it seems different for computer vision service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/ where they charge a transaction for each feature even grouped in one call

Comment: @fred_ Taken from [What is the Azure Face API?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/overview): _The face detection feature is also available through the Computer Vision API, but if you wish to do further operations with face data, you should use the Face API_

Comment: Still one more clarification in addition to what @fred_ asked.
In case of face match, is it two detections plus one match (IsIdentical) [POST {Endpoint}/face/v1.0/verify] or is it two detections only?
For large volume transactions one third cost is large.